# how to call for separate procedures using the ifelse any? function in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo, patch, procedure

In brief below is the code I wrote to show whether there is a turtle on the neighbor patches

```
to play-the-game
  ifelse any? turtles-on neighbors4
  [show "turtles-found"]
  [show "turtles-not-found"]
end
```

I need to change it to perform the procedures I have already written out;
if they are the same breed they 'gain-energy'
different breed 'fight-opponent'

I am not sure as to how to change the first part to carry out the other procedures.

Comment: Hi, did Luke's answer and/or my answer address your problem? Please feel free to add more detail / further specify your question if none of the answers did, or accept an answer to mark the question as closed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to check the `breed` of both the asking `turtle` and the 'opponent' `turtle`. You're certainly on the right track by checking if there are any neighbors present, the next step is to make the `breed` check and then the turtles can choose what action to take. For example, look at this toy model where wolves and cows can identify whether they've landed on a patch next to the same breed or not:

```
breed [ cows cow ]
breed [ wolves wolf ]

to setup
  ca
  ask n-of 10 patches [ 
    sprout-cows 1 [ 
      set shape "cow" 
      set color white
    ]
  ]
  ask n-of 10 patches with [ not any? turtles-here ] [
    sprout-wolves 1 [ 
      set shape "wolf" 
      set color red - 1
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  ask turtles [
    face one-of neighbors
    fd 1
    play-the-game
  ]
  tick
end

to play-the-game
  if any? turtles-on neighbors4 [
    let current-neighbor-turtle one-of turtles-on neighbors4
    ifelse [breed] of current-neighbor-turtle = breed [
      show "I see one of my own breed!"
    ] [
      show "I see an opponent!!!"
    ]      
  ]
end
```

If that's not quite what you had in mind, please edit your question above to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider dropping `ifelse`. In your example, the two possible outcomes of the `any? turtles-on neighbors4` condition are mutually exclusive: either there are turtles, or there are not.

However what you want to achieve in your model is a bit different: (I imagine that) on the neighboring cells there can be turtles of the same breed AND turtles of a different breed at the same time. In this case, the two scenarios are not mutually exclusive and using `ifelse` (where only one or the other of the two command blocks will be executed) would potentially overlook one of the two cases, depending on how you specify the condition.

I think two `if` statements would be more appropriate:

```
to play-the-game
  if (any-friends-nearby?) [gain-energy]
  if (any-opponents-nearby?) [fight]
end

to-report any-friends-nearby?
  report (any? (turtles-on neighbors4) with [breed = [breed] of myself])
end

to-report any-opponents-nearby?
  report (any? (turtles-on neighbors4) with [breed != [breed] of myself])
end
```

It is still relevant for you to choose which condition will be checked first (and therefore which action, between `gain-energy` and `fight`, will be executed first in case both conditions are satisfied)