# How to call for different strategies in netlogo using the IF or Ifelse statement

Tags: netlogo

so below is the outline for a two player game in netlogo. I have only attached a portion of the code which is what we have been given to manipulate. I am getting a syntax error when I do try to run the game.
Our aim is to get the turtles to either gain energy if they find a neighbor of the same breed or fight the opponent of the different breed.

```
to play-the-game
  ifelse any? turtles-on neighbors4 
  [show turtles-found] 
  [show turtles-not-found]



to gain-energy
  set similar-nearby count ( turtles-on neighbors4 )
 with
  [color = [color] of myself]
  set total-nearby count (turtles-on neighbors)
  ;
  ;
  if (similar-nearby >= total-nearby - similar-nearby)
  [set energy energy + 5]
end

to fight-opponent
  let my-breed [breed] of green-players
  let my-color [color] of green-players
  let opponent-breed [breed] of red-players
  ;
  ;;
  ask my-breed
  [check-random-winner]

end

to check-random-winner
  let pick random-float 2
  let winner nobody
  ask turtles
  [if winner = nobody
    [ ifelse size > pick
      [set winner self ]
      [set pick pick - size] ] ]
end

to change-opponent
  ask red-players
  [ set breed green-players
      set color green ]
end
```

We need to change the show statements to call for either gain-energy or fight once the breed has been identified depending on the strategy selected in the chooser global. (1 being to gain-energy, 2 being to fight).

Comment: Can you specify the error you are getting? Can you provide a [mre] as I suggested in [this previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70226216/getting-ask-expected-input-to-be-an-agent-or-agentset-but-got-the-list-green-p)? How does this question differ from [this other one you already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204396/how-to-call-for-separate-procedures-using-the-ifelse-any-function-in-netlogo)?

Answer (score 0):

One issue is your first function (play-the-game) is missing an end statement.

I'd suggest putting parenthesis on your if statements just to confirm. This looks uncomfortable: `if any? (turtles-on neighbors4)`
I forget how netlogo interprets that since it's a few nested function calls.

Comment: NetLogo uses round brackets only for determining the order of operations. For example, `if any? turtles-on neighbors4 []` is equivalent to `if any? (turtles-on neighbors4) []` which is equivalent to `if (any? turtles-on neighbors4) []`. The only difference between those is style (I prefer the last one as I like to always have conditions in parenthesis). However, `if any? turtles-on neighbors4 with [color = red] []` gives an error (i.e. `color` is not a patch variable), while `if any? (turtles-on neighbors4) with [color = red] []` runs smoothly, bc NL understands that `color` refers to turtles

Comment: Nice! That really clears things up.

Comment: Glad! However I didn't mention the only other use of parentheses in NL: some commands (namely `list`, `word`, `sentence`, `map`, `foreach`, `run` and `runresult`) can take a varying number of inputs. When you want to pass them a number of inputs that is different from the default, you need to enclose the whole command in parentheses. For example: `list 4 7` is ok, but `list 4 7 1` gives an error: you need to have `(list 4 7 1)`. Also `(list 4 7)` works, btw. Just thought it is best to note this other use of parentheses in case someone new to the language happens to read my comment above